# VBA - How can i add value to a public array - compile Error

Tags: vba, ms-word

I add some values to my array and try to get it later in another method.
Unfortunately i get an compline error for my array when i try to get the value.

The values for the array comes from my UserForm, where some checkboxes could be selected. While closing the UserForm a method runs and controlls which checkboxes are activated, if the checkbox value is true the name of the checkbox should be add to the array

```
'''ThisDocument Code
Public Processes As Variant 'This is the Array
Public numberOfProcesses As Integer

'''UserForm1 Code
public sub controllProcesses()

    numberOfProcesses = 0
    
    If cbLogin.Value = True Then
        numberOfProcesses = numberOfProcesses + 1
        ReDim Processes(numberOfProcesses)
        Processes(numberOfProcesses - 1) = "Login"
   End If

   If cbRegistration.Value = True Then
       numberOfProcesses = numberOfProcesses + 1
       ReDim Processes(numberOfProcesses)
       Processes(numberOfProcesses - 1) = "Registration"
   End If
End Sub

'''Method to get value from array
Public Sub Examples()
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer
    
    b = 1

    With Selection
        For a = 0 To numberOfProcesses
            .TypeText Text:=b & ". " & Processes(a) ' Here the compile error appears.
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

From what I could find via my search, it should actually work like this, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you get an *compiler* error (for me, the code compiles), or do you get a runtime error. What does the error say?

Comment: Yes i receive an compile error. Error says *Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined* and `Processes(a)` is highlighted.

Comment: It looks as though you have declared the variables in the *ThisDocument* module. Move the declarations into a standard module.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Thank you very much, with this hint I was able to solve my problem.